# PHP - switch Array condition

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

I have an array with user group ids

```
$arr_user_group = array();
```

and a Query that select all users from my Database with their user group

```
array_push($arr_user_group, $row3['group']);
```

result with print_r($arr_user_group);

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 [3] => 5 [4] => 1)
```

now what i need is to assign each number ([...] => number(2,5,3,5,1)) a name like

```
1 = Admin 
2 = Member
3 = Ipsum
4 = Lorem
5 = Guest
```

...what is the best way to do this?
my output on the page is for example "2" but i need the name "Member"

```
if( isset($arr_user_group[0]) && '5'=== $arr_user_group[1] ) {

 $arr_user_group[1] = "Group5"; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr_user_group = array(2, 5, 3, 5, 1);

$groupNames = array (1 => 'Admin', 
                     2 => 'Member',
                     3 => 'Ipsum',
                     4 => 'Lorem',
                     5 => 'Guest');

$lenght = count($arr_user_group);

for ($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++) {
    $arr_user_group[$i] = $groupNames[$arr_user_group[$i]];
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr_user_group, true) . '</pre>';

//print

Array
(
    [0] => Member
    [1] => Guest
    [2] => Ipsum
    [3] => Guest
    [4] => Admin
)
```

Comment: @Daan Timmer : yes, I just wrote the minimal answer without checking for errors. You could check with an isset for the group_name if necessary. Since the data come from a database anyway, if it was my project, I would create a table groups (id, name) and get directly the group name with the query and a join.

Comment: I would do the same indeed :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr_user_group = Array(2, 5, 3, 5, 1);

foreach($arr_user_group as &$group) {
    switch($group) {
        case 1: 
            $group = 'Admin';
            break;
        case 2: 
            $group = 'Member';
            break;
        case 3: 
            $group = 'Ipsum';
            break;
        case 4: 
            $group = 'Lorem';
            break;
        default:
            $group = 'Guest';
    }
}

print_r($arr_user_group);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Member
    [1] => Guest
    [2] => Ipsum
    [3] => Guest
    [4] => Admin
)
```

**Note:**
As you are receiving the array from the database it would be better to create a new table (user_groups) with two columns: `id` and `name`. Then you can get the group name with a simple `JOIN` in your query.

Comment: the number after Group was only an example :) The usergroup range is from 0 to 5

Answer (score 1):

Or you can go this way if you want pre-defined names instead of groupX:

```
<?PHP

$arr_user_group = Array(2, 5, 3, 5, 1, 10, 0);
$arr_group_names = Array("None", "Admin", "Member", "Ipsum", "Lorem", "Guest");

foreach($arr_user_group as &$element) {
    $element = ($element < count($arr_group_names)) ? $arr_group_names[$element] : $arr_group_names[0];
}

print_r($arr_user_group);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Member
    [1] => Guest
    [2] => Ipsum
    [3] => Guest
    [4] => Admin
    [5] => None
    [6] => None
)
```

You can of course set a different 'default' value. This way you can have your group names coming from a database, where your `$arr_group_names` is filled from a DB. Probably easier to manage instead of hard-coding them.

**Update:**
I've used count() directly within the loop. This might occur a significant performance penalty if you have a lot of elements in $arr_user_group because each iteration count is recalculated. It is better to assign `count()` to a local temporary variable (outside the loop). But for this example it is easier to show it like this.

Answer (score 1):

For a more complex solution with switch this should work:

```
$arr_user_group_in = Array(2, 5, 3, 5, 1);
$arr_user_group = array_map(function ($id) { 

switch($id){

    case 1:
        return 'Admin';
        break;

    case 2:
        return 'Member';
        break;  

    case 3:
        return 'Ipsum';
        break;  

    case 4:
        return 'Lorem';
        break;  

    case 5:
        return 'Guest';
        break;

}

}, $arr_user_group_in);

print_r(array_combine($arr_user_group_in, $arr_user_group));
// output: Array ( [2] => Member [5] => Guest [3] => Ipsum [1] => Admin )
```

Note that the `5` as a duplicate key will only appear once in the result.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this?

```
foreach ($arr_user_group as &$id) {
    $id = "Group$id";
}
```

or

```
$arr_user_group = array_map(function ($id) { return "Group$id"; }, $arr_user_group);
```